# ArcMap: ImportError: No module named sklearn.neighbors

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool, kernel-density, scikit-learn

I have tried to create my own Kernel Density Estimation tool in ArcMap, but when importing the sklearn.neighbors module I get the following error:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
ImportError: No module named sklearn.neighbors
```

I am using Arcmap 10.6.1. The latest compatible version with this ArcMap is scikit-learn 0.18.2.

Can someone explain where and how to install this module?

Edit: I have tried to use the commands to install scikit-learn module, but this returned a syntax error.

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python -m pip install scikit-learn==0.18.2
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python -m pip install scikit-learn==0.18.2
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Have you installed the ```scikit-learn``` module? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html What OS are you using?

Comment: I have not installed the scikit-learn module for Arcmap yet. I have tried to, but using the commands returns a syntax error: invalid syntax.  Note that since Arcmap 10.6.1 is using python 2.7.14 the latest version of scikit-learn won't work. My OS is Windows 10.   @Pfalbaum

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.